# Guzzle retrieve headers without body, using GET

Tags: php, guzzle

I would like to get the response headers of an url, example:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->head('http://example.com/');
echo $response->getStatusCode();
```

I cannot use `HEAD` requests because some web server doesn't recognize HEAD requests (sometime they return 403 forbidden or internal server error).

Is there any way to get headers with guzzle without doing HEAD?

### Clarification

I want to get just the headers and not the full body response. Imagine i want to check the headers of a large file, if i use get, Guzzle will download all the file and I don't want that

Comment: I think you might be confusing the HTTP verb HEAD with a request for headers. Any Guzzle response object will allow you to get the headers of the response.

Answer (score 1):

Like benJ said, you might be confusing the HTTP verb HEAD with a request for headers. You should use the right verb in this request and then get the headers from the response. See this working example with a GET request:

```php
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->get('http://example.com/'); // use the method according to the http verb, e.g. POST will be ->post('http://example.com/')
$headers = $response->getHeaders();
```

Comment: hey, thanks. I have added an explanation in my original post. I don't want to download the full body that's why i can't use get

Comment: @giò So I think `->head()` is right and the problem you're having is something else. A head request should work just like a GET request. Are you sure you won't get a 403 if you use the same parameters on a GET request? Could you try replacing `->head()` with `->get()` and checking the status code?

Comment: some old web server doens't support HEAD